# Check maven version using inspec

Tags: inspec

I have a inspec test as shown below

```
describe command('mvn -version) do
  its('exit_status') {should eq 0 }
end
```

on running the test case is failing as exit status after running the command on the machine is coming 127. But I can confirm that maven is installed on the machine and when I test exit status manually on the machine , it's 0

Comment: Try adding tests for the `stdout` and `stderr`, you can just check `eq ''`. That will show you the command output, which will probably tell you more about why it is failing. Might be a missing `$JAVA_HOME` or similar since InSpec commands don't get some shell init variables.

Comment: I used stderr at least come to identify the error it was due to command not found. But I can run the command on the machine and maven is also added to the path doi need to provide absolute paths.

Comment: Depends on how your environment variables are set, but abs paths for anything not in /usr/bin or similar would probably be wise :)

Comment: thanks my issue is resolved now.Used absolute paths.